# Bad: How can I migrate a table to a database in Laravel using terminal?

Tags: laravel

I am getting an error when I try to migrate a table from the migration directory to a database.
I want to migrate:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --path=/database/migrations/2020_04_17_08144_create_car_production_dates_table.php
```

But I got this error.

```
 Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException 

  File does not exist at path C:\Users\Yared Sisay\OneDrive\Desktop\Laravel\ProjectOne//database/migrations/2020_04_17_08144_create_car_production_dates_table.php.
```

Comment: sorry this is the what I want to migrate php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2020_04_17_08144_create_car_production_dates_table.php

Comment: Why do you need to specify the path?

Answer (score 0):

What about path without `/`?

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/2020_04_17_08144_create_car_production_dates_table.php
```